# Why I cannot cache items in Redis until they are modified in Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, redis

I have an ASP.NET Core app in which I am caching the items from database tables to Redis cache to get fast response. I delete the cached items whenever there is a change in the database in order to keep database and Redis in sync.

For some tables, they do not get updated very often maybe every 2 months or so. So, I thought it would be a good idea to keep items cached indefinitely. However, all the articles I read suggest emphasize on determining an expiration value for the cache.

Here is an excerpt from my code, it is not well-polished but just to show you my concept:

```
public class CachedRepository<T> : ICachedRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

    private string CacheKey = typeof(T).Name;
    private MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheOptions;

    public CachedRepository(IRepository<T> repository, IDistributedCache dcache)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _distributedCache = dcache;

        var expiration = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25)
        };
    }

    public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity, bool save = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        string key = CacheKey + "-" + entity.Id;
        
        // Remove all items since the cache is not consistent anymore
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(CacheKey);

        return await _repository.AddAsync(entity, save, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities, bool save = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {            
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(CacheKey);
        return await _repository.AddRangeAsync(entities, save, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity, bool save = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        string key = CacheKey + "-" + entity.Id;
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(CacheKey);
        await _repository.DeleteAsync(entity, save, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task DeleteRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities, bool save = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            string key = CacheKey + "-" + entity.Id;
            await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
        }

        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(CacheKey);
        await _repository.DeleteRangeAsync(entities, save, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(string id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            string key = CacheKey + "-" + id;
            var result = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key);

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IgnoreReadOnlyFields = true,
                IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true,
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
                DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
            };

            var value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(result, options);

            if (value == null)
            {
                var item = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id);

                if (item is null) 
                    return item;

                await _distributedCache.SetStringAsync(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(item, options));

                return item;
            }

            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> ListAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var result = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(CacheKey);

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            IgnoreReadOnlyFields = true,
            IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true,
            ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
        };

        var value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(result, options);

        if (value == null)
        {
            var item = await _repository.ListAsync();

            if (item is null || item.Count() == 0)
                 return item;

            await _distributedCache.SetStringAsync(CacheKey, JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<T>>(item, options));

            return item;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity, bool save = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        string key = CacheKey + "-" + entity.Id;
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(CacheKey);
        await _repository.UpdateAsync(entity, save, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's always better to set expiration time, no matter if they expired with no hits since after the first request you put it in the cache again.

Comment: @sa-es-ir, do you think if I specified the expiration to be almost a week that would be logical in my case?

Comment: For me 1 day is too much, IMHO, when a table won't touch in a week why we need a cache for them!